# AWS Load Balancer https issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, load-balancing

I was trying to setup the load balancer for our servers. if use the http, it works fine. But when I switch to https，　I got following errors in the browser console:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.something.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '...mootools.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

I thought I did some hard code like "http://www.something.com/library/....",
but I did not, I only use the "/library/...." for including the javascript files.

When I set up the load balancer, it was asked me to setup the port for listening. I set as  https , load balancer port: 443 forward to instance port 80.

Is anybody knew how could I solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The forwarding back to 80 isn't responsible for it. This is either HTML that is hardcoded to http or a redirect/server-generated URL pointing to http.

Use the network panel of dev tools (like in Chrome's menu) and inspect each request until you find the culprit.

Here's an example, using this question page. I've selected an insecure request.

[image: network analysis]